# Java: Extend functionality of listener method from another class

Tags: java, inheritance, xmpp, smack

I thought of creating a separate class for all of the smack's basic methods like connecting, login, sending message, receiving messages.

So, there's a listener method which receives messages.

```
static ChatManagerListener chatManagerListener = new ChatManagerListener() {
        @Override
        public void chatCreated(Chat chat, boolean createdLocally) {
            chat.addMessageListener(
                    new ChatMessageListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void processMessage(Chat chat, Message message) {
                            System.out.println("MESSAGE RECEIVED: "+message.toString());
                            messageReceived(message);
                        }
                    });
        }
    };
```

Message is received and passed to messageReceived() method.

SITUATION:

Now, when I import this class into other, I would like to extend the functionality of this **messageReceived()** method, so the whole process remains abstract and the developer only deals with incoming messages. Or, somehow this **messageReceived()** method push the message to that other class.

Comment: Can you change ChatManagerListener?  It would be a straight forward implementation to use a Factory (for instance) here.  (Also, can you change it to ChatListenerManager?  lol)

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to define another listner to manage the message.

This is a working snippet example (of a prototype, so it's ugly and without any pattern) to update the GUI of reciver user.

If you'll need something else keep in mind that you'll need plugins (PacketInterceptor) on server side.

```
/*MessageGuiUpdate.java*/
    public interface MessageGuiUpdate {

        public void displayMessage(String body);
    }



/*XmppManager.java*/
public void init() throws XMPPException, SmackException, IOException {
private MessageGuiUpdate guiUpdate;
 //FOO
 //BAR

/* init() */
        this.chatManager = ChatManager.getInstanceFor(connection);


        this.chatManager.addChatListener(
                new ChatManagerListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void chatCreated(Chat chat, boolean createdLocally)
                    {
                        if (!createdLocally)
                        {

                            chat.addMessageListener(new IncomingMessageListener());;
                        }
                    }
                });
}

/*nested class*/
    class IncomingMessageListener implements ChatMessageListener {
        @Override
        public void processMessage(Chat arg0, Message message) {
            String from = message.getFrom();
            String body = message.getBody();

            if (body != null)
            {
            System.out.println(String.format("============ Received message '%1$s' from %2$s\n============", body, from));
            guiUpdate.displayMessage(body);
            }

        }

    }

/*CustomGui.java*/
public class CustomGui implements MessageGuiUpdate {
//foo

@Override
public void displayMessage(String message) {
    System.out.println("I've just recived: "+message);

}
}
```